# Reclaimed floor boards vs roof boards: what's the difference?

Tags: wood, flooring

I'm looking for some reclaimed pine floorboards to match the floor they'll be helping fix. [This place](http://www.bensreckyard.co.uk/all-products?s=&q=12&cat=6) (for example) lists both reclaimed floorboards and roof boards— is this the same thing? Could I get roof boards and use them in a floor?

Answer (score 1):

Get the dimensions you need first, then judge by looks. My guess is that the roofing boards would be lower grade (ie, more knotty) than floor boards.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect floorboards to be planed to tight thickness and width tolerances and to be relatively smooth on one side. Roof boards can be sawn rougher with more tolerance for variation in thickness and width.

Frankly though, it could very well be that the only difference is where they were pulled from!